# change arrow function to normal function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function to play the previous video am using the arrow function

Here is my solution

```
  $('#interactive-layers').on('click', ".go_back", function () {
        videohistory.pop();
        var hist = videohistory[videohistory.length - 1];
        videohistory.pop();


        if (hist[0].movieid == 4) {

            let movieData = movies.find(({
                movieid
            }) => movieid == 23);
            hist.push(movieData);
            playVideo(hist[3], hist[1], hist[2]);
        } else {
            playVideo(hist[0], hist[1], hist[2]);
        }
    });
```

This works fine in chrome, safari, firefox but in Internet explorer, I am getting the following error.

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
```

How to change this function so that it can be compatibility with all browsers?

Comment: `movies.find(function(movieId) { return movieId == 23; });` *However* your next issue will be that `array.find()` isn't supported in IE either. There's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for that though

Comment: import polyfills rather than changing back to traditional JS

Comment: @EugeneSunic there's no polyfill for arrow functions, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This,

```
$('#interactive-layers').on('click', ".go_back", function () {
        videohistory.pop();
        var hist = videohistory[videohistory.length - 1];
        videohistory.pop();

        if (hist[0].movieid == 4) {

            // Here I change the Arrow function with the es5 normal one.
            /*
               let movieData = movies.find(({ movieid }) => movieid == 23);
             */
            let movieData = movies.find(function(movieid){
              return movieid == 23;
            });
            hist.push(movieData);
            playVideo(hist[3], hist[1], hist[2]);
        } else {
            playVideo(hist[0], hist[1], hist[2]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please add some comments about what you have changed?

Comment: Done, I am only replaced the find callback function from Arrow function syntax to es5 normal syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to the normal `function` instead of an arrow function. But keep in mind that you have used argument destructuring in the `array.find()` so you need to handle it properly while converting, like this:

```
let movieData = movies.find(function(entry) { return entry.movieid == 23; });
```

Also, I wouldn't use `let` either to make sure it will run on all IE browsers. MDN states that it has partial support on IE so... use `var` instead to support all IE browsers.

Another thing mentioned above is that `array.find()` itself is not supported by IE, so you need to import a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)